# adding one project class files with xib on one tabbar

Tags: iphone, xib

is it possible to add one xcode project into other project? I have a project with three .xib files and need to add into other and to open all its functionality first tab.is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

just drag them to ur project and popup will come and tick in copybox....that it and with reference type default